# multiple strpos ignores first value

Tags: php, strpos

Ii want to find specific words in a text. Therefore I build an array and turn the values over to the `strpo_arr`-function. Here I split a `textarea` into its sentences and look in every sentence about these specific words, to highlight this sentence. This works, but if I have a target on the first sentence of this sentences-Array, the output of the part `$sentence` is empty. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!!

```php
function strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {
   if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
   foreach($needle as $what) {
      if(($pos = strpos($haystack, $what))!==false) return $pos;
  }
  return false;
}

$sentence = " ";
foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
   if(strpos_arr($sentence, $searchStringArr)){
      $subContent .= "<span class='highlight'> $sentence</span> ";
   }else{
      $subContent .= " ".$sentence;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you give examples for `$sentences` and `$searchStringArr` when you have the problem?

Comment: $sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $text);
first $sentence = "Wir kümmern uns um alle notwendigen Unterlagen ( z.B. Zeich­nungen & Berechnungen ) und gehen mit Ihnen alle notwendigen Schritte, die zur Genehmigung Ihres Bauvorhabens führen."

one of that values in $searchStringArr = "kümmern"

I have allready tried to strip out the phrase "z.B." manually, but the issue is the same. 

Thanx!!!

Comment: What PHP version do you have?

Comment: i´ve got 5.6.28

Comment: This is working for me with the example you gave. Where exactly is `$sentence` empty for you?

Comment: In the first sentence you´ve got the word "kümmern". if i go throw my array $sentences brings me a goal on the first sentence ( Wir kümmern uns ... ), but i only get an emtpy span-tag ( this is, what i see in the firebug: <span class='highlight'>   </span> ).
this drives me crazy - particularyl if you can´t copy this issue ;-(((
Nevertheless - many thanx for support!!

Comment: any ideas for this issue?

Comment: Can you show code where `$searchStringArr` and `$text` are set?

Comment: Hi and thanks for checking that out

foreach($stringSearch as $str){
 $searchStringArr = explode(",", $str->bt_search );
}

The text is split of in its sentences:
$sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $leistungsmerkmal->am_beschreibung);

Many Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the problem. My last guess is maybe there's something to do with encoding and special characters. I'd go through and print values to determine exactly where it fails and under what conditions.